# Export of information for list of LeanIX-IDs

Tags: export, leanix

We use the application [LeanIX](https://www.leanix.net/en/) for application management. I exported a list of LeanIX-IDs out of the application. I want to enhance this information with more data from their respective factsheets.

My approach was to (somehow) get the IDs back into the Inventory search. This would make the search result equal to the list of IDs and i'm ultimately able to enhance it by adding more columns to the result.

Is there any way to enhance an exported list of IDs with more information from their respective factsheets?

As an Example: I have a list of LeanIX-IDs of factsheet type "Application" and want to enhance these by their description.

Comment: If someone could create and add the tag LeanIX it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for sharing your input. We at LeanIX, take very seriously our customer questions and we are happy to provide information to make your experience with the tool even greater.

1. When you export the data directly from the inventory you have the possibility to select additional columns. In fact, it is a best practice to only chose the columns that you intend to add/amend the information. For more details about export, please see here: https://docs.leanix.net/docs/import-export-your-data#section-export
2. As an admin of the tool, it is also possible to export all your data via changelog or snapshot, that option allows you to export all your entire data in a nice and organized excel file. For more information please check the link:
   https://docs.leanix.net/docs/conduct-a-data-snapshot
3. In the example that you mention about adding information in regards to  "description", it is possible to select that specific column and import the information back to the system. Please follow the next instructions:
   Inventory - select Application Fact Sheet type - select "As table" (top right) - select the column "Description" - click on Export.

Do you think this information going in the right direction? Please let us know in case of additional questions. We are very happy to further assist.

We wish you a nice LeanIX experience.
Your LeanIX support team

Comment: Option 2. is probably "good enough" for me. My complete problem is a bit more complex and needs in SQL-terms: a "two-stage join": I got the list of Application IDs and want to have for each ID for the linked supplier the linked internal group that is responsible. So basically: application join supplier join user group.

Answer (score 0):

We do this (almost) every day. There are a few options:

**The easiest way:**

1.1. Export all applications and fields

1.2. Copy the exported sheet into the Excel file with the data to be enhanced. Now you have 2 sheets in one file: Your ID list and your application list

1.3. Use this formula to look up the description field in the other table:

```
=INDEX(Applications!D:D;VERGLEICH(A2;Applications!A:A;0))
```

(Assuming your ID column is A in both sheets, your exported sheet is called "Applications" and the Application description is in column D)

**The faster way (if you do it more often)**

2.1. Use Excel Get & Transform (formerly Excel Power Query) to skip the export step and load the LeanIX applications directly into Excel.

2.2. - see 1.3 -

**The ultra-fast way (only worth it if you do it really often)**

3.1. Use the script language of your choice (we use Ruby and Python) to load the list of IDs

3.2. Use the LeanIX API to add the required fields to your list

3.3. Write an output Excel or CSV file.

Also, if you would like to join our LeanIX community to engage with ~10-15 other companies using LeanIX, feel free to get in touch. New members are very welcome!